# Is the subset relation on the powerset of a set, with qualification, reflexive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

I was wondering if the subset relation is reflexive?

$R = \{(X, Y ) \in P(A)^2\mid X\subseteq Y \text{ and } X \neq Y \}$

I assumed they it was reflexive since for all $X \in P(A), X \subseteq X$ is true. So does that mean the relation is reflexive? Or do I need to add additional proof?

Comment: That's a confused use of the phrase "a subset of a powerset." It seems you mean, "Is the subset relation on the pwoerset a reflexive relation?" At least, that is what the rest of your question appears to be asking. But then you start using $S1$ and later reference $R$, which is nowhere defined. $S1$ explicitly forbids $(X,X)\in S1$. Not sure what $R$ is meant to be.

Comment: sorry will make edit.

Comment: **Note:** While $X\subseteq X$ is true, however $X\neq X$ is false, so $(X,X)\not\in R$.

Comment: If  X ⊆ X that means X = X? or are you referring to the condition in the relation that X != Y?

Comment: You've also got an odd arrow - you are trying to prove that $(X,X\in R$, so what you seem to want to say is that $X\subseteq X\rightarrow (X,X)\in R$. The other direction doesn't get you anything. $X+2=Y$ implies $Y<X$, but $Y<X$ does not imply that $Y=X+2$.

Answer (score 2):

The relation cannot be reflexive. $(X, X)\in R$ if and only if both the following statements are true:

$$X\subseteq X\tag{1}$$ $$X \neq X\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ is true for all $X \in \mathcal P(A)$. $(2)$ is false for all $X \in \mathcal P(A)$.

Hence, for all $X \in \mathcal P(A)$, $(X, X) \notin R$.